# Runtime binding of XML Schema to Java code

Tags: java, binding, xsd, runtime

The situation is thus:

I have an application which provides editing capabilities to XML an file. This file follows a certain Schema. The Schema belongs to a subset of Schemas which actually follow a line of evolution from one to another - so they are not so different from one another.

The main difference between the schemas is an enumeration of string labels.

I now have need to save "meta data" in XML format (This is a second type of XML file). This "meta data" contains a list of labels from the set enumerated in the schema.

The application can accept a new schema at runtime and adjust itself.

Therefore I have an XML file that must be validated by two schemas one static containing the basic structure of the "meta data" stored in the XML and one which contains the 'proper' label enumeration. The latter schema is determined at runtime.

I have glanced over JAXB, XMLBeans and JiBX.

I can't figure out what technology to choose that would allow for a runtime bind of code and schema in the way that would most benefit my use-case.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with "binding"? Or do you just need to validate in the runtime?

Comment: Firstoff I wish to validate at runtime, once that is done I wish to have handy objects representing the data in the file so I can proceed to do something "interesting" with them.

Comment: Are your users editing the XML file directly in your application? As opposed to having them work at a higher-level of abstraction?

Comment: Your guess (I guess) is correct, they do get to work on a higher level of abstraction and are not "aware" of the underlying XML file.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem Yaneeve?

Comment: Sorry @SachinSharma, I had not solved the problem straight forwardly... It's been a long time since this problem had come up, and I have since moved projects. If memory serves, we did not implement this "advanced" capability, but opted for less power and a single complete schema file loaded wholly at runtime without any manipulation to it...

Comment: Thanks for response @Yaneeve It seems there is still no solution to the problem you faced. The only accepted way for xsd binding using JAXB or XStream (may be) is to create static java objects in a first run of compiling the xsd(xml) and then use these classes in your project. There is nothing which can give me these classes in runtime. Now I realize that its asking for too much actually. The solution which I need is not practical. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an article on validation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi.html).

As for "handy objects" - well, you actually can compile an XML schema into Java classes - even with JAXB even in runtime. The problem is that you can't really profit from the classes created in the runtime since your code does not know them.

I'd be thinking in the direction of some XML Schema APIs (like [XSOM](https://xsom.dev.java.net/)).

Comment: I'll take a look at XSOM - sounds interesting

Comment: There are alternatives (Xerces Schema API  http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/index.html, for instance), check what better suits your needs.